# saving multiple vectors with different lengths in one matrix

Tags: matlab, reshape, cell-array

hope you can help me out here...
I'm trying to add vectors with different size to matrix ,but there is error "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."

How to convert it to cell array?

That's what i have done:

```
for i = 1:m
[image] = imread(imageFile{i});
[x y]=size(image);
Vector=reshape(image,1,x*y);
matrix=[matrix;Vector];

end
```

Comment: See: [MATLAB's cell array documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

Comment: `c_matrix{i} = Vector;`?

Comment: it result 1*m cell array but i need it to be (m*1)

Comment: Then `c_matrix{i,1} = Vector;`

Comment: thanks it works correctly

Comment: how to export c_matrix{80,1} to cvs file where c_matrix{1,1} conatins {1,n} cell array ?